# How can I run " Html" samples (from kinect v2 sdk samples) outside of visual studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, kinect-sdk

I am very new to web programming, specially Microsoft web technologies, So I'm sorry the question is not clear enough.

(This question isn't really about kinect functionality, it is about running a kind of visual studio project).

If you open "Kinect sdk browser v2", you will see some projects with "Html" suffix, like "FaceBasics - Html".these are windows 8 apps with web interface.

My question is : "How can I run this projects outside visual studio?"I want to run the project locally. (I can't find any .exe file.)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the project is built with visual studio go to project_name/bin/debug directory and you'll find the built .exe file.

Comment: no there isn't, even if I build it . I think there is no .exe for this type of project.

Comment: Could you run the project from inside visual studio? I couldn't even build it due to windows developer licensing issue.

Comment: yes . I can run it in visual studio ultimate but couldn't run in VS express.